# Getting Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server ........ , Name or service not known

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, asp.net-mvc-5

I've configured Desktop docker with the following images

- SQL Server 2019
- ASP.NET 5 app

The SQL Server works fine (I've succeeded to connect it with SQL Server Management Studio from my local Windows and also checked with telnet from the app image which looks ok) but from my ASP.NET app I get the following message

> Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server ........ , System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known"

I've tried several variation of connection string but I still have the same problem.

```
"connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server={ip\server name}\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Rocky;Integrated Security=True;User Id=myId;Password=myPsw;"
}
```

Anything I've missed ?

Comment: You have `Integrated Security` set to `true`, but then define a Username and password; that doesn't make any sense. If you're using Integrated Security you, by definition, don't define a Username and Password and the credentials of the Windows User the application is running as are passed to the instance.

Comment: In your .json file do you have one backslash seperating the instance name (`Server=ServerNameOrIpAddress\MSSQLSERVER;`) or two (`Server=ServerNameOrIpAddress\\MSSQLSERVER;`)? The latter is correct, the former is not.

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` usually stands for the (internal) instance name of the **unnamed** instance - to connect to this, you typically should *not* provide the instance name - only the machine name (or ip address). So try `Server={ip\server name};Initial Catalog=Rocky` and let us know if that works

Comment: If you are using a named instance you need SQL Browser to be started and available over the network. If you want the default instance, leave off `\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: `Integrated Security` is the problem.  But if you do want to use `Integrated Security` then configure the container to use gMSA, otherwise set it to `False`.  Also, if the MSSQL Server only has one instance then just use the IP/Machine name without adding the instance name. This may help: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: About the security true , I removed the User Id and the Password  and so In the  Server param i  defined only the IP but still get the same error :( .  besides the error point to a problem with the connectivity if I understand

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the problem.

1. I had more then one image of this project in my docker.
2. the appsettings.json in the container was not update and the connection string was different, I guess it used an old version of image. after cleaning all the images changing the server to IP and redeploy it started working.

Thanks for everyone.